# Why GCP LoadBalancer doesn't support the ECDSA certificate?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, tls1.2, kubernetes-ingress

I have created kubernetes ingress with frontend config and the ECDSA P-384 TLS cert on Google Cloud Platform, after few seconds of creating process i received the followind error:

> Error syncing to GCP: error running load balancer syncing routine:
> loadbalancer *******-default-******-ingress-******* does not exist:
> Cert creation failures -
> k8s2-cr-*****-******************-****************** Error:googleapi:
> Error 400: The ECDSA curve is not supported.,
> sslCertificateUnsupportedCurve

Why The ECDSA curve is not supported? Is there any way to enable this support?

Create tls-secret command:

```
kubectl create secret tls tls --key [key-path] --cert [cert-path]
```

Frontend-config:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
  name: frontend-config
spec:
  redirectToHttps:
  enabled: true
  responseCodeName: MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: default
  labels:
    kind: ingress
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: frontend-config
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - '*.mydomain.com'
    secretName: tls
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: spa-ingress-service
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: api.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: api-ingress-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

spa services:

```
# SERVICE LOAD BALANCER
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: spa-service
  labels:
    app/name: spa
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app/template: spa
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
---
# SERVICE NODE PORT - FOR INGRESS
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: spa-ingress-service
  labels:
    app/name: ingress.spa
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app/template: spa
  ports:
  - name: https
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
```

api services:

```
# SERVICE LOAD BALANCER
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-service
  labels:
    app/name: api
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app/template: api
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
---
# SERVICE NODE PORT - FOR INGRESS
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-ingress-service
  labels:
    app/name: ingress.api
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app/template: api
  ports:
  - name: https
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
```

kubectl describe ingress response:

[image: describe]

Comment: Can you try to change the certificates to P-256.I think the following error is due to an incompatibility with the P-384 certificate currently being used.

Comment: Yes, it is works if I use SHA-256 with RSA Encryption cerftificate. Do you suggest that this is a SHA bits problem rather than ECDSA? @BakulMitra

Comment: ECDSA P-384 is incompatible with that I am saying. But if you use SHA-256 the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gcp [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs#private-key) supports **RSA-2048 or ECDSA P-256** certificates.  Also DownstreamTlsContexts support multiple TLS certificates. These may be a mix of RSA and [P-256 ECDSA](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/security/ssl#certificate-selection) certificates.

The following error is due to the incompatibility with the P-384 certificate currently being used rather than the P-256 certificate.

For additional information refer to the [Load Balancing Overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal).